# How to use @default trait?

Tags: constraints, traits

I am new to smithy. I have a smithy structure:

```
namespace example

structure Identity {
    @required
    name: String

    @default(30.0)
    age: Double 
}

structure Address {
    @required
    street: String

    @required
    city: String

    @required
    zipCode: String
}

structure Person {
    @required
    identity: Identity
    address: Address
}
```

I expected when I build to get 30.0 as age, however I am getting `null`.

```
Person.builder().withIdentity(Identity.builder().withName("exampleName").build()).build()
```

Can anyone help me how to define a structure with default attribute?